# wordpress comments on posts goes straight to trash

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, comments, posts

My website has been up and running for more than 3 months and was working fine until today, I just discovered that all comments made goes straight to trash.

I did not install new plugins, I don't have akismet. It just started. I have deactivated all my plugins and yet the issue persists. I don't know what the issue is.

Is there any code I need to add to my functions.php file to make this stop?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not post it here. My friend blacklisted a lot of names. This made any comment with any of those names go straight to spam or trash.